# How do I determine if internet file exists on server?

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

Until recently I have used HttpWebRequest to determine if a file exists on the internet. But now, I realize that a server could handle the 404 if it did not exist and I would only get the default 404 server error page. In this scenario, the HttpWebRequest **would not throw an exception.** I can't think of a way to tell if there was a 404 error that occurred.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Check the `StatusCode` and `StatusResponse` in the `HttpWebResponse`.  You can always `throw` based on the value received.

Comment: If I understand correctly, isn't it the `GetResponse` method that is throwing a `WebException`? In such a case, the response has not been received.

Comment: Can you provide an example for that please? I tried employing your idea but I can't get it to solve my problem.... Do you cast the returned WebResponse to a HttpWebResponse? ----- (HttpWebResponse)await request.GetResponseAsync();

Answer (score 0):

On a server that returns a 'page not found' page, if you try to get a nonexistant file in your browser and look in the dev tools, the return code is still 404 Not Found.

Normally, you would expect the `HttpWebRequest.GetResponse` method to return an http response code but instead [.NET throws an exception](http://www.motobit.com/tips/detpg_net-getresponse-404/) for http errors.

```
try {  
    HttpWebRequest httpReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.contoso.com");
    using (HttpWebResponse httpRes = (HttpWebResponse)httpReq.GetResponse())
    {            
        if (httpRes.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            Console.WriteLine("\r\nResponse Status Code is OK and StatusDescription is: {0}", httpRes.StatusDescription);
        // Releases the resources of the response.
        httpRes.Close();
    }
}
catch (WebException ex) {
    Console.WriteLine("Error returned: {0}",ex.Response);
    // can throw again here.
    throw;
}
```

Comment: Hmmm... that is a good idea. Sorry for my ignorance, but how do I access the return code?

Answer (score 0):

If `GetResponse` or its async equivalent is throwing, catch the `WebException` and you'll find it has a number of handy properties.

In particular, [WebException.Response](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexception.response.aspx) could be very useful to you.